# Databinding in user control inside another user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, aspx-user-control

I have a DataBoundControl (Calendar.cs). It is a calendar that I can fill with events that are painted in it (The calendar shows the entire month and each day is divided in 24, showing different colours depending on the event that is on that hour).

Inside each day of the calendar, I have a button that opens a UserControl with the detail of the day clicked (DetailedDay.ascx). The control show all the events in that day, showing some info about them. In this user control, you can click on the event and this will open another form with the detail of the event. The event can be of different types (opening differents forms depending on the type of the event, for example EventsXXX.ascx), so this functionality is defined on the page (aspx) containing the Calendar by a delegate method.

The problem that I have is that I want the DetailedDay.ascx.cs to refresh the painted data after I change the hour of the event in EventsXXX.ascx

Right now, I am passing the events of the day in the Show method of the DetailedDay.ascx, but this obviously won't work after I change the info of one event.

I would like a way to pass the info to DetailedDay.ascx that could being refresh on postback.

Maybe something like defining an ObjectDataSource in the aspx page but that could be accessible in the control DetailedDay (remember that it is contained in another user control Calendar).

Or something like accessing parent user control (Calendar) to take the information through it.